# NHIbernate Linq group by count

Tags: linq, nhibernate, group-by

I have the version 3.0.0.1001 nhibernate.

My objects are basically modeiling a lineup at an event. So I have a StageSet object which represents one slot in the schedule for a stage.

Each StageSet object has a Stage and an Act property.

It also has many Users - people who have favorited the set.

I'm trying to ascertain the most popular sets that have been favorited using the following linq:

```
var topStars = from s in Db.StageSets
                           group s by s.Act.Id into g
                           select new { SetKey = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

However this just fails with a Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available] error

Should I be able to do this?

w://

Answer (score 3):

in case someone comes here. The following should work with NH 3.1

```
var topStars = from s in Db.StageSets
               group s by s.Act.Id into g
               select new { SetKey = g.First().Act.Id, Count = g.Count() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've specified the query correctly in linq.  NHibernate is refusing to translate it.

Comment: Hmmm - is there a way i can do this in HQL?

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your query with a slightly different domain and it worked. But that will count StageSets by Act, NOT favorites.